# Is it safe to launch/close kernels in the middle of a parallel calculation?

Tags: parallelization

It appears that it is possible to launch additional kernels (or close existing ones) *during* a parallel calculation.  The newly launched kernels will be utilized for the rest of the calculation.

Here's a simple way to test and illustrate this (in a fresh kernel):

```
LaunchKernels[2]

Parallelize[
 Table[Pause@RandomInteger[20]; $KernelID, {i, 8}],
 Method -> "FinestGrained"
]
```

Now use `Evaluation -> Interrupt Evaluation...` to interrupt the
evaluation and go into a subsession.  In the subsession evaluate

```
$KernelCount (* check that we only have 2 kernels *)

LaunchKernels[4] (* launch 4 more *)

Return (* return from the dialog *)
```

Notice that when the `Table[]` finally finishes, we get results between
1 and 6 (I got `{2, 1, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}`). This means that all 6 kernels have been utilized during the rest of the evaluation, even though some kernels were only launched in the middle of the calculation.

It is also possible to close some kernels during the calculation.  In another test I got the following messages ...

[image: Mathematica graphics]

... and the calculation seemed to finish correctly.

**Question:** Is it safe to do this?  Can this break anything if the timings are wrong?

---

Consider some code like this:

```
(* This uses LaunchKernels[] to launch more kernels
   as compute resources become available: *)
manageKernels[] := ...

(* ensure that manageKernels[] is always evaluated on the master kernel *)
SetSharedFunction[manageKernels] 

Parallelize[
 Table[manageKernels[]; compute[i], {i, 100}],
 Method -> "FinestGrained"
]
```

Is this going to be safe?  What if `manageKernels[]` uses `CloseKernels[]` as well?

Comment: I wondered if you'd figured this out yet.  I use Mathematica's parallel processing capabilities a lot and have started to develop a check list of do's and don'ts so as not to get in trouble.  Things like: how to recover after aborting a calculation (sometimes one can't); starting kernels manually rather than programmatically (always more reliable in my experience). I find the facility powerful and fast, just a bit rough around the edges.  I wonder if it would make sense to create a list of rules of thumb for getting the most out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's safe to add a kernel, but if you close the kernel the calculation is working with, the calculation will never finish! I once had this problem. But I think adding a kernel when you are calculating shouldn't affect your answer.

Hope my answer helps you.

Comment: So, under what circumstances doesn't requeueing work properly? That's the essence of Szabolcs's question.

Comment: I had a similar experience: adding seemed to work, but there were various issues with closing.  Most often though the dead kernel was automatically re-launched.